# How to exit a SET /p in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I exit a SET /p command after a certain time? For instance, if a user takes too long to input something, I want to exit the SET /p.

Answer (score 6):

This is a pure Batch solution that avoid the problems that the Batch-JScript hybrid script have when Sendkeys is used and the original window is not in focus.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Execute a SET /P command with time out
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem If this file is re-executed as pipe's right side, go to it
if "%~1" equ "TimeoutMonitor" goto %1

del InputLine.txt 2> NUL
(
   set /P "line=You have 10 seconds to complete this input: " > CON
   > InputLine.txt call set /P "=%%line%%" < NUL
) 2> NUL | "%~F0" TimeoutMonitor 10
set /P "line=" < InputLine.txt
del InputLine.txt
echo Line read: "!line!"
goto :EOF


:TimeoutMonitor

rem Get the PID of pipe's left side
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FO TABLE /NH > tasklist.txt
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in (tasklist.txt) do (
   set "leftSidePipePID=!lastButOnePID!"
   set "lastButOnePID=%%a"
)
del tasklist.txt

rem Wait for the input line, or until the number of seconds passed
for /L %%i in (1,1,%2) do (
   ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
   if exist InputLine.txt exit /B
)

rem Timed out: kill the SET /P process and create a standard input line
taskkill /PID %leftSidePipePID% /F > NUL
echo/
echo Timed Out> InputLine.txt

exit /B
```

Comment: This has a dependency that the current user has RWXD permissions on the current directory. There is no guarantee that this is the case.

Comment: @BILL
issue sed 's/InputLine.txt/"%TMP%"\\InputLine.txt/g' over your script and it's solved, right, assuming the user has write access to %TMP%, else replace %TMP% with any path you wish, provided you use sed to search/replace, you will have to escape \ with '\\'. Another option would be to open the file in notepad.exe and do a search and replace. Search:InputLine.txt Replace:"<somePathTheUserCanWriteTo>"\InputLine.txt

These are environment questions Aacini cannot guess and are usually trivial to fix; you must admit, he did the hardest part.

Comment: This is an older post, but this answer intrigues me and I'm curious how this works if you're using this from within a Batch file - how does this not kill the calling Batch script?  Certainly something along the lines of `Start Call "%~dp0TimoutMonitor" "needlessArg"`?  Using `Start Call` has been most consistent for me to asynchronously run the file in its own window, but how does it return the value of input if this is the method of calling?  In some limited testing, I do not see that `set /p` alone will open a new instance of `CMD` for which to grab the latest `PID`

Comment: Forgive me - I did some testing - I can see now that it's the `pipe` which opens the new instance of `CMD` - very good.  And it must be that the "Command Block" (if you will) by having the `set /p` and `> InputLine.txt` inside parentheses `()` is what causes the entire chunk to be piped into the file itself regardless . . .?  And sending `stdOut` to `CON` - even for a `set /P` command - this allows `CON(sole)` to hold the processing of `set /P` while maintaining the environment?  See https://ss64.com/nt/con.html - I hope I'm getting close to understanding this feature.  Very very cool.

Comment: Last comment on this tonight - By outputting this to `CON(sole)` - it is storing the `CON` device within the piped output into the new instance of `CMD` as a staging area, the 2nd portion of the pipe calls itself for the timer, kills `the piped instance of CMD stored in _CON_` and allowing line outside of block (`set /P "line=" < InputLine.txt`) . . . and - since the 1st `set /p` is _stored in `CON`_, this is how the `CMD` interpreter passes back the value of the 1st `set /p` since it's `CALLED` from within the originating bat's environ...  Closer?  2> Nul is to get rid of the err from pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you can't.

You may be able to use `choice` to accept a single character with timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Below there is a Batch-JScript hybrid script that achieve what you want. JScript is installed with every version of Windows from XP on. Save this file with .bat extension:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
rem Give the desired wait time in milliseconds:
start "" /B Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" 10000
set "input=Time out"
set /P "input=You have 10 seconds to complete this input: "
echo Input read: %input%
goto :EOF


@end


WScript.Sleep(WScript.Arguments(0));
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: This solution only "works" if the focus is on the console window when the SendKeys method sends the Enter keystroke. Thus this isn't a really robust solution.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart This is probably the best you can get.

Comment: @JohnDOE - IMO editv32/editv64 is a better and more robust solution.

Comment: "If a downloadable tool is permitted" that is your own word. @Aacini 's answer works by default. That is why its "best" you can get.

Comment: It only works if focus does not change. Hence it is unreliable in many scenarios. If you cannot use downloadable tools, then `choice` or `timeout` commands may be preferable.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: You are right. I fixed this problem in my [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143549/how-to-exit-a-set-p-in-a-batch-file/28196468#28196468). Thanks for noting this problem. `;)`

Comment: @JohnDOE: I developed an even better solution! See my [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143549/how-to-exit-a-set-p-in-a-batch-file/28196468#28196468).

Answer (score 0):

If a downloadable tool is permitted, you can use editv64.exe (64-bit) or editv32.exe (32-bit) with the `-t` parameter. For example:

```
editv64 -p "Enter something within 10 seconds: " -t 10 INP
```

The tool has additional advantages, such as hiding the input string when typed (`-m`) as well as editing an existing environment variable interactively. You can download it here:

http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html