# TIMEOUT.EXE alternative for legacy Windows OSes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sleep, pause

I am trying to write a batch script that is as universal across Windows versions as possible (or at least from XP to 10). Everything is compatible so far (just some echoes and variable setting), except it uses the TIMEOUT.EXE command, which isn't available in XP or below.

I tried copying the exe over to no success. I was wondering if, through some clever coding, if this is possible. I basically need it to wait X amount of seconds before continuing, or allow a keypress to continue.

I tried using sleep.exe from the server 2003 utilities pack while piping it to `set /p "="` and vice versa, but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/432322/how-to-sleep-in-a-batch-file) they suggest using the `ping` command if you want universal compatibility. Not sure if you can stop it with a keypress though.

Comment: @Banex just tried that command to no avail. it waits but wont stop with a keypress. thanks regardless

Comment: You are going to have a hard time finding an alternative option that allows a key press.  So your question should really say **AND allow keypress to continue**.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686109/778560) may help you...

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command that offers a default option together with a timeout.
For instance:

```cmd
rem /* Wait for 10 seconds and take the default choice of `0`;
rem    you can interrupt waiting with any of the keys `0` to `9` and `A` to `Z`;
rem    you cannot use punctuation characters or white-spaces as choices: */
choice /C 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ /D 0 /T 10
rem // The `ErrorLevel` value is going to be set to a non-zero value.
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of ways. [PING](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php) seems to be the most popular. You can try also

with w32tm

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:5 /dataonly /samples:2  1>nul
```

or wtih typeperf:

```
typeperf "\System\Processor Queue Length" -si 5 -sc 1 >nul
```

with mshta:

```
start "" /w /b /min mshta "javascript:setTimeout(function(){close();},5000);"
```

Comment: odd, I tried your first w32tm command and I got a `start "" a` fork bomb that ran right after that. cool. and it didn't allow a keypress to stop it. ill try the second.

Comment: yeh, second one pauses, but won't allow a keypress to stop it. thanks regardless

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest of tools, but using choice with a custom message and a timeout of (5 seconds in this demo), with keystroke interrupt (any key, besides <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> etc.)

```
@echo off
choice /c qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890 /cs /n /M "Timeout is 5 seconds.. press any key to Continue." /D c /T 5
echo 1 > null
```